# In android, sqlite text field is retrieved using getBlob, not getString

Tags: android, ruby, sqlite

I am attempting to make an android application with a pre-populated database. When learning about how to go about this, I came across this article http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/ , which basically takes an existing sqlite database and streams it into the correct location on the android device. The data I had was dealt with in ruby, so I grabbed the sqlite gem, and created a database like so.

```
db = SQLite3::Database.new( "cards.db" )
db.execute("CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT DEFAULT \"en_US\")")
db.execute("INSERT INTO android_metadata VALUES (\"en_US\")")

db.execute("
  CREATE TABLE #{@@card_table_name} (
  _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT UNIQUE
  )")

cards.each do |card|
  begin
    db.execute("INSERT INTO #{@card_table_name} (_id, name) VALUES (?, ?)",
               card.id, card.name)
  rescue => e
    puts "#{card.name} (#{card.id})"
    puts e
  end
end
```

When I go into the database, both the one made from the ruby script, and the one from using adb and examining the database on the emulator, I get this for the schema.

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE Cards (
  _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT UNIQUE
  );
```

However, when I pull the data back out in my application, getString can't deal with the name, specifically, this block gets into the exception clause, and prints the name successfully within that block

```
Cursor cursor = myDataBase.query("Cards", new String[] {"_id", "name"}, null, null, null, null, null, "5");
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    try {
        cards.add(new Card(cursor.getInt(0), new String(cursor.getString(1))));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        byte[] blob = cursor.getBlob(1);
        String translated = new String(blob);
        Log.i(MagicApp.TAG, "DB retrival blew up on " + cursor.getInt(0) + ", " + blob + " : " + translated);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I can deal with that, but it seems like I shouldn't have to do that. Any one else encountered this, or know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please define "getString can't deal with the name".